# How to hide Top Navigation Bar For Given Role in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, navigationbar

I want to hide top menu navigation bar when user role is "ERP USER", logout link should be remains there. or how to remove navigation item "My Profile", "My Account" & "My Dashboard". due to some security access in third party application i need to disable this navigation items.

Can anybody explain me how to accomplish my requirement?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove *My Profile*, *My Dashboard* and *Control Panel* entries by modifying portal configuration, the rest requires some development. First two will disappear if you set followig options in *portal-ext.properties* to *false*:

```
#
# Set whether or not private layouts are enabled. Set whether or not private
# layouts should be auto created if a user has no private layouts. If
# private layouts are not enabled, then the property
# "layout.user.private.layouts.auto.create" is assumed to be false.
#

layout.user.private.layouts.enabled=true
layout.user.private.layouts.auto.create=true
#
# Set whether or not public layouts are enabled. Set whether or not public
# layouts should be auto created if a user has no public layouts. If public
# layouts are not enabled, then the property
# "layout.user.public.layouts.auto.create" is assumed to be false.
#
layout.user.public.layouts.enabled=true
layout.user.public.layouts.auto.create=true
```

That you will disable User's private and public pages (and remove them from dockbar).

To get rid of *Control Panel*, you have to revoke *Access Control Panel* permission in Roles configuration (usually for *User* role).

Your other two requirements - hiding *My Profile* or removing *Dockbar* will require more effort.

- To get rid of *My Profile* you will need to create JSP hook for Dockbar portlet (in version 6.2 it should be https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/dockbar/view_user_account.jspf).
- The easiest way to hide dockbar for specific role is to implement role checking in *portal_normal.vm/ftl* of your theme. In standard *unstyled_* theme you have to change the following lines https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.0-ga1/portal-web/docroot/html/themes/_unstyled/templates/portal_normal.ftl#L21-L23

Comment: It's more easier to hide Dockbar in version 6.2. i check given role in view_user_panel.jspf page and then show hide the required navigation item.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove navigation bar using Liferay theme from **portal_normal.vm** for specific user. Apply this theme to your current site.